# Pitch correction on pitch correction

Tags: pitch-issue

I'm working on an American movie that was dubbed in German for PAL. Since there is a lot of music and singing it was pitch corrected to sound right at PAL speed.  Now we're doing a blu ray version at NTSC speed (slower). Obviously since there was pitch correction introduced into the PAL the NTSC will be not only slower and a lower pitch but slightly off key. I can correct with my Pro Tools audio suite Pitch Shift, (1.047:1 with speed correction) but there are anomalies.  I'm hearing pulsing in steady notes and some my tracks drift and create echos.  My Accuracy setting is at zero. I know there is software and plug-ins that do this job much better.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Is there a reason an NTSC version is being made from the PAL version, when there's apparently already an NTSC version out there in the world?

Comment:  There is an NTSC M&E but without the specific vocals per language well as the rest of the foreign dialogue. This is a mixed 5.1 German print master. A whole new recording of the vocals would have to be made and the original German dialogue stem added to create the new German NTSC print master. Very expensive. It appears all PAL languages were pitch corrected.  Oh well.


Answer (score 1):

Seratto Pitch 'n Time has been the defacto plug in for this type of work. However, you will still have some aretfacts as a result of this process.

I am assuming that this is something like an old MGM musical or the like, where the singing wasn't dubbed in German. If so, I would suggest doing so editorial - using the non pictch corrected NTSC English for the musical numbers and the German newly pitch corrected track for the remainder of the film.

Randall Smith

Comment: It's actually a new direct to video animated movie, released domestically today.  Unfortunately there's no budget for remixes of the foreigns for Bluray.






Answer (score 0):

I have learnt that there are variances in the algorithms used for the same function by different Audio Products. You can use the same Auto Pitch correction in Adobe Audition. I am sure these look familiar to you. *In Audtion you can access this by Selecting the Sound Clip and Effects -> Automatic Pitch Correction*

[image: Automatic Pitch Correction in Adobe Audition]

If you think you have Pitch Shifts (Pitch is changing linearly as a function of time) you can use *Effects -> Time and Pitch -> Stretch & Pitch*

If you still have imperfect results. You will have to do manual Pitch correction. A very good tutorial is here

. I don't know about your S/W but audition's graph make it really easy to edit the pitch on a section by section basis as it gives a good idea of the original pitch in comparison.